# Audio difference between Android Marshmallow and Lollipop

Tags: android, audio

I am using external Audio that connects to the Audio Jack which record bytes
Using the Device on Android < 6 works well.
but on Android > 6 it doesn't work at all..
i got Permissions.
anyone knows the difference between the Two Version of android. (Hardware/Software) any clue where to look ..

Exception : AudioRecord-JNI: Error -4 during AudioRecord native read

Thank you

Comment: I am having the same: "AudioRecord-JNI: Error -4 during AudioRecord native read" message. There is no crash, but I suspect this error is affecting  the SpeechService that operats one layer above my Voice Recorder. (Google Speech Cloud)